# Code will loop itself three time and runs "If" statement twice and "Else" statement once

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i do not know why but this bit of code repeats itself 3 times when adding "questionwords" in the message, specifically it will run the else statement one and the main if statement twice.

```
bot.on('message', function(message) {
    const words = message.content.split(' ');

    if (words.includes('sans')) {
        var questionwords = ['can', 'is', 'was', ];

        for (i in questionwords)
            if (!words.includes(questionwords[i])) {
                if (message.author.bot) return;
                var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

                if (chance == 0) {
                    message.channel.send('<:annoying_sans:520355361425981440>');
                }

                if (chance == 1) {
                    message.channel.send('<:sans:519723756403425294>');
                }
            } else {
                var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

                if (chance == 0) {
                    message.channel.send('Maybe.');
                }

                if (chance == 1) {
                    message.channel.send('Yes.');
                }

                if (chance == 2) {
                    message.channel.send('No.');
                }

            }

    }
});
```

Comment: `message.channel.send(...)` triggers `bot.on("message", ...)` again ...

Comment: What is the value of `message` being passed in, is it a string `"questionwords"`?

Comment: There are 3 elements in the questionwords array and you're looping over it, so the if/else runs 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you want to know if the words in the `questionwords` array were in the message.  You already know how to check a single word using `Array.includes()`, but multiple words are more complicated.

If you just want to know if any word in the words array matches any word in the questionwords array, you can use `Array.some()`:

```
var wereAnyFound = words.some(word => questionwords.indexOf(word) > -1);
// true or false
```

Maybe you want to make sure they are ALL in there, use `Array.every()`:

```
var wereAllPresent = words.every(word => questionwords.indexOf(word) > -1);
// true or false
```

Maybe you want to know how many, or you want to get the matches (`Array.filter()`):

```
var matches = words.filter(word => questionwords.indexOf(word) > -1);
// an array of matches

var howMany = matches.length;
// number
```

Answer (score 0):

Like James said in the comments, because there are three words in the questionwords array, your for loop will run three times. It will then reply once for each word.

However, if you remove the for loop and change

`if (!words.includes(questionwords[i]))`

to

`if (!words.includes("can" || "is" || "was"))`

you'll get the same result without the bot repeating itself, as it will search for "can" *or* "is" *or* "was" instead of "can" *and then* "is" *and then* "was".